# how to Get by Id data from database Blazor C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, blazor-server-side, data-access-layer

already have started crud with blazor serverside to get data from database

i am working now to create a page where i will see details and edit one item of a list

i got the id of the item i want to display but my crud solution give me a list of object not just one llike i need....

i got my SqlDataAccess where i code the two main function (load -> QueryAsync, and Save -> ExecuteAsync) with its interface like below :

[image]

And i got a FiledbData class from where i call db like below :

[image]

i want now just to ask the database for one item like an getbyId instead of get all data ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parameterized queries` to execute an where clause.

Therefore the `GetFile` method would be like this:

```
public Task<FileModel> GetFilebyId(int id)
{
    string sql = "select * from dbo.file.. where Id = @Id";
    return _db.LoadSingleResult<FileModel, dynamic>(sql, new  {Id = id });
}
```

Also you need to add a new method `LoadSingleResult` like below(other parts apart from `try` section are similar to your `LoadData` method):

```
public async Task<T> LoadSingleResult<T,U>(string sql, U parameters)
{
   .
   .
   .
   try{
       var data=await connection.QueryAsynch<T>(sql, parameters);
       reurn data.Single();
   }
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Note that:

- The id column assumed to be `Id`.
- The id column assumed to be an `integer` column

You can use [QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync](https://dapper-tutorial.net/async#querysingleordefaultasync) too.

Comment: thank you @Mehrdad Dowlatabadi for your answer, it was clear and it working !

Answer (score 0):

Add a `where` clause to your DB SQL query and create an overload of GetFiles() that takes an ID value which will be interpolated into the SQL query:

```
public Task<List<FileModel>> GetFile(Guid id)
{
    string sql = $"select * from myTable where Id = '{id:D}'";

    return _db.LoadData<FileModel, dynamic>(sql, new  { });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Andrew H, its ok but i don't ask for a list... your code return me a List<FileModel> with one item ... my question was for how to return just one FileModel not a List...

Comment: You can use LINQ to select a single item using a predicate:

    myList.Select(item => item.Property == SOME_VALUE);